# Models loaded with Assimp have messed up UVs/normals

Tags: opengl, assimp

I've been trying to use Assimp to load models and so far I got it to load a few obj models, but all of them have messed up UVs (and maybe normals).

Here's what it looks like :

[image]

I tried several combinations of Assimp's loading flags, but to no avail.

Here are the used flags :

```
const aiScene* scene = importer.ReadFile(path, aiProcess_Triangulate | aiProcess_FlipUVs|aiProcess_GenSmoothNormals|aiProcess_ImproveCacheLocality|aiProcess_FixInfacingNormals|aiProcess_FindDegenerates|aiProcess_FindInvalidData|aiProcess_GenUVCoords|aiProcess_TransformUVCoords);
```

I'm only loading already triangulated (with Blender) obj models with no submeshes.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Maybe remove the "genUVCoords" flag

Comment: @Bálint: Already tried that and didn't change anything :/

Comment: Well, try to remove every flag, and add them one by one back, see which one's the problem

Comment: Something I need to mention  is that I just tried with no flags at all (0) and the same behavior happened...

Comment: Also, I had already written a simple obj loader and it loads all of the above models correctly

Comment: Ok, I found the problem after a few tests and it was in the way I was storing UVs, so the problem didn't come from Assimp.

Comment: Should I delete the question ? As it's not relevant in fact :/

Comment: Post your findings as answer and mark it correct.

Comment: Never delete questions before they are at least 30 days old, or it'll have a negative impact on your account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually didn't come from Assimp but from the way I internally stored assimp's UVs. I didn't take into account the fact that there can be no UVs some times and thus, I had random values when there were none.